# Matlab merge two structs to one single array

Tags: matlab

I have to identical structs. How can I combine the two values of the struct to an array efficiently?

```
foo1.b = 1
foo2.b = 2
```

How can I merge these two variables to... `foo1` and `foo2` to...

```
foo.b = [1 2]
```

Comment: I think the only way to do this is to iterate over all fields and all elements of the struct array.

Answer (score 1):

You can just do:

```
>> foo.b = [foo1.b foo2.b]

foo = 

  struct with fields:

    b: [1 2]
```

Comment: Yes but I would like to have a function. Since .b isnt the only struct field. E.g. fun(foo1,foo2,foo3,...) etc... Further I can have an array... foo(i).b, in that sense

Comment: @WG- All that information (function, several fields, arrays) should have been initially included in the question

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pretty rudimentary try at a function that combines structures. The only condition is that the structs need to all have an equal number of fields/members. It was a bit of a piecing/glueing code together but...

The input signature `varargin` (variable input arguments) allows a variable number of inputs into a function. The `nargin` variable indicates the number of input arguments. By using a bit of trial and error the right types can be created. The function `fieldnames()` allows for the retrieval of the field names within the structures inputted.

```
%Structure 1%
foo1.b = 1;
foo1.a = 2;
foo1.c = 5;

%Structure 2%
foo2.b = 3;
foo2.a = 1;
foo2.c = 4;

%Structure 3%
foo3.b = 5;
foo3.a = 2;
foo3.c = 7;

%Function call%
[foo] = Combine_Structures(foo1,foo2,foo3);
foo.a
foo.b
foo.c


%Function%
function [foo] =  Combine_Structures(varargin)

Number_Of_Fields = numel(fieldnames(varargin{1}));
Field_Names = fieldnames(varargin{1});


Number_Of_Inputs = nargin;
Variable_Input_Arguments = varargin;
Argument_Array = (1:Number_Of_Inputs);
    
Structures = Variable_Input_Arguments;


for Field_Index = 1: Number_Of_Fields
Field = string(Field_Names(Field_Index));

Combined_Array = [Structures{1:Number_Of_Inputs}];
Combined_Array = [Combined_Array(1:Number_Of_Inputs).(Field)];


foo.(Field) = Combined_Array;

end

end
```

**Using MATLAB version: R2019b**